# Calling method from self.parentViewController does nothing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

After dismissing my second view controller, I would like to call a function in my first view controller.

The code I am using now is this

```
firstViewController *fvc = (firstViewController *)self.parentViewController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {
    [fvc someMethod];
}];
```

But it seems that the method is never called, I added a UIAlertView to the method so it would be called the moment the method is called too.

```
firstViewController *fvc = (firstViewController *)self.parentViewController;
[fvc someMethod];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This totally fails too, I don't get any error from both ways.

Comment: You should probably try using `self.presentingViewController` instead of `self.parentViewController`

Comment: If this works, I'll turn it into an answer to give more details

Comment: @rdurand yes, that works for me. I will accept once u have turn it into an answer

Comment: Nice ! I added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
firstViewController *fvc = (firstViewController *)self.parentViewController;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {
    [fvc someMethod];
}];
```

You should use presentingViewController insteadof parentViewController when self is being presented

like

```
firstViewController *fvc = (firstViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {
    [fvc someMethod];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

As rdurand said, try presentingViewController instead. Also, would be very helpful if you could put in a NSLog() in your code to show you what's in fvc at the point of method invocation. rdurand is probably right that your fvc pointer is nil, so you're invoking the method on nothing. If the method isn't activating, then there are really only a few  possibilities:

1. Your line of code is not executing
2. It's executing, but you're invoking the method on a nil object
3. The method is executing, but on a different object than you're expecting

Set a breakpoint, look at your VC pointer, make sure the code is following the path you think it is. Pretty standard debugging task, unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, [the UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states :

> **parentViewController**
>
> The parent view controller of the recipient.
>   (read-only)
>
> `@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *parentViewController`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> If the recipient is a child of a container view controller,
>   this property holds the view controller it is contained in. If the
>   recipient has no parent, the value in this property is nil.
>
> Prior to iOS 5.0, *if a view did not have a parent view controller and
>   was being presented, the presenting view controller would be returned*.
>
> On iOS 5, ***this behavior no longer occurs***. Instead, use the
>   presentingViewController property to access the presenting view
>   controller.

So basically, they did not really remove `parentViewController`, but the behavior you could expect before iOS 5 when your view controller doesn't have a parent view controller has changed.